# Create afterRevokeCustomerAccessToken plugin magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, after-plugin

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService">
        <plugin name="segment_logout_plugin" type="New\Hm\Plugin\RevokeCustomerToken" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin

```
<?php

namespace New\Hm\Plugin;

class RevokeCustomerToken
{

    protected $logger;
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function afterRevokeCustomerAccessToken(\Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService $subject, $result,$customerId) {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/RevokeCustomerToken.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($customerId);
    }

}
```

I am trying to add a afterplugin on `revokeCustomerAccessToken()` from `app/code/Magento/Integration/Api/CustomerTokenServiceInterface.php`

But it does not seems to be working.
Any correction needed ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

> You can plugin the interface `Magento\Integration\Api\CustomerTokenServiceInterface` instead of the implementation class `Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService` which
> you have tried to pluginize

*it will work not tested though*

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Integration\Api\CustomerTokenServiceInterface">
        <plugin name="segment_logout_plugin" type="New\Hm\Plugin\RevokeCustomerToken" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`New\Hm\Plugin\RevokeCustomerToken.php`

```
<?php

namespace New\Hm\Plugin;

class RevokeCustomerToken
{

    protected $logger;
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    
    /**
     * Revoke token by customer id.
     *
     * The function will delete the token from the oauth_token table.
     *
     * @param CustomerTokenServiceInterface $subject
     * @param int $customerId
     *
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterRevokeCustomerAccessToken(CustomerTokenServiceInterface $subject, $customerId)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/RevokeCustomerToken.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($customerId);
        return $customerId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks i will check this answer.

Comment: Hi can you please help me here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330620/how-to-determine-if-customer-is-new-or-existing-from-customer-save-after-data-o ?

Comment: Why plugin the interface ?