# How to determine if customer is new or existing from "customer_save_after_data_object" event ? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer

Here is my events.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_after">
        <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerRegister" name="customer_register_observer"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

CustomerRegister.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Vendor\Module\Helper\Tracking;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CustomerRegister implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
  */
 
 protected $_registry;
 protected $request;
 /**
 * ...
 * ...
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
 */
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var Tracking
     */
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, Tracking $helper, \Magento\Framework\Registry $_registry,\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_registry = $_registry;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * Call helper & pass customer object
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/getActionName.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('action'.$this->request->getActionName());
            if($this->_registry->registry('custom_var')){
                return $this; //this method has already been executed once in this request (see comment below)
            }
            $this->_registry->register('custom_var', true);
            $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
            $this->helper->trackCustomerRegister($customer);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts how can i differentiate, customer is new in this observer ?
As this also calls on customer update.

Any reviews appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I am not getting how to trigger event only when customer is new

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an observer on the `customer_register_success` event, which is dispatched in `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`, right after the customer account was created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the application i am working in it uses graphql, so this event does not trigger

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the customer attributes "created_at" and "updated_at" are equal.

```
if ($customer->getCreatedAt() == $customer->getUpdatedAt()) {
   // Do whatever you need
}
```